# How to get server MySQL version in PHP without connecting

Tags: php, mysql

I need to echo the MySQL version in a PHP script (it's a server requirement check page for users before downloading the plugin) without having them connect to their database.

The upload this script to their server and open it in the browser. I could ask them to run php info but all I need is the Mysql version and it gets formatted in the script with the rest of the results.

How should i go about this?

Comment: Until you have connected to a mysql server, there is no way to find out what version any server may or may not be running. The best you can hope for is to find the version of the client that is installed not the server version.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have access to the command line mysql executable you can try this:

```
function getMySQLVersion() { 
  $output = shell_exec('mysql -V'); 
  preg_match('@[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+@', $output, $version); 
  return $version[0]; 
}
```

For the client version:

```
print mysql_get_client_info();
```

Without shell access to get the server version you must connect first:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
if (!$link) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
print "MySQL server version: " . mysql_get_server_info();
mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: A lot of hosts don't allow shell-exec. Any other way?

Comment: That will be the client version. A lot of hosts have the server on a separate machine.

Comment: Unless you have access to run shell commands on the server then you won't be able to get the MySQL version without establishing a connection.

Comment: Unless your wanting the MySQL client version and not the server version? The MySQL client version is what shows up in a phpinfo() request.

Comment: I need the actual Mysql version as the client version. i ended up making them connect first. Thanks guys.

Comment: Modified my answer with a way to get the client version.

Comment: Nice. `mysql_get_server_info()` is easier in PHP than `SHOW VARIABLES`.

Comment: On WAMP (Windows) mysql_get_client_info() displays a long string, not only value, and the client version will not match with the server one. On LAMP servers usually they came at once when install and are same version. Anyway, to get only the value on the windows: `$info = mysql_get_client_info(); 
preg_match("/[0-9.]{6}/", $info, $value); 
echo $value[0];`

Comment: Just an updated side-note. As of PHP 5.5.0 all `mysql_*` seems to become deprecated. And so, the `mysql-get-client-info` function. Take a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-get-client-info.php).

Comment: mysqli version: `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
print "MySQL server version: " . $mysqli->server_info;
$mysqli->close();`

Answer (score 16):

You'll need the user to enter their DB credentials, so you can connect to the MySQL server and run the following query to get the MySQL server version:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version'
```

Here's the output on my server:

```
Variable_name     Value
----------------------------
version           5.1.53-log
```

Comment: Well thanks guys. I'm going to have to make them enter their DB info I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Information output by `phpinfo` should be accurate. 
Just add the following to a file & visit it in the browser:

`<?php phpinfo();` & find the mysql version under `mysql >> Client API version`

[image]

Comment: `phpinfo()` reports "Client API library version => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev" but the actual MySQL version is 5.6.33.

Comment: Seems odd @bancer were you able to find an explanation? Was it inside of a VM?

Answer (score 2):

mysql_get_client_info() is deprecated. For PHP 7 and above you have to use:

```
echo mysqli_get_client_info();
```